# PHP - MySQLi prepared select with join not working

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, inner-join

So I'm trying to do a `select` query with an `inner join` using prepared statements, it look like this:

```
if ( !$prepared = $link->prepare('SELECT * FROM ? INNER JOIN Members ON ?.Member_UID = Members.Member_UID') ) {
    exit('Could not prepare the query! :S');
}
```

That will return `false` and exit the script because the query could not be prepared of course, what am I doing wrong.?

Comment: You cant parameterize table names

Comment: So I just insert the table var inside the query? Is that secure?

Comment: Depends on where it comes from, if the source is not trusted use a whitelist of table names to compare against before insertion.

Comment: Well I do sanitize the variable, it has to be 4 characters long only. So I suppose that will keep the query safe, right ?

Comment: Validation of the tables would be safer, sanitizing *may* prevent injection but could still allow for the breaking of the query.